# Visual studio include visibility

Tags: c++, visual-studio, portability

I got issue with includes in visual studio. I want to compile the project both for windows and linux.

In visual studio, I got a tiny class in .hpp file, which uses `std::exception` and `std::is_pod<T>` but I did not include `type_traits` nor `stdexcept`!! And the file compiles just fine with Visual Studio! Why?

Doing so on linux gives me error

```
In file included from Packet.hpp:3:0,
                 from AbstractPacketFactory.hpp:2,
                 from AuthenticationPacketFactory.hpp:2,
                 from AuthenticationPacketFactory.cpp:1:
ByteSerializer.hpp: In member function ‘byte_serializer& byte_serializer::operator>>(T&)’:
```

linux g++ is correct - why does visual studio not warn me? Is there something I can do about it? I am using VS as my primary IDE and I would like to avoid such surprise in future (currently there are 50 errors like that...)

Comment: There is no requirement for the C++ Standard Library to **not** include other files, as long as the as-if rule holds. The C++ Standard Library that ships with Visual Studio (what version are you using anyway?) appears to include header files for its own implementation. If you need to fix this, there's nothing you can do but compile it for all destination platforms.

Comment: These are probably included by some other standard header you have included.

Answer (score 0):

I got a function where i made a mistake:

```
static_assert(std::is_pod<T>, "T must be a POD");
```

You have to use it with `::value` or `()` - yet visual studio compiles `std::is_pod<T>` it without any warning. And that was the reason of error avalanche...

Answer (score -1):

Your Visual Studio Projects might be configured to use Precompiled Headers to use.  stdafx.h is there when you use Precompiled Header.

Just remove stdafx.h from Precompiled Headers and see if Compilation succeeds on windows.

You can find Precompiled Headers in Project Properties > C++ > Precompiled Header.

If you want to make cross platform projects you should remove that Precompiled setting.

Comment: You do not include the precompiled header file in other **headers**. And the code already compiles with Visual Studio. Your proposed solution is a fix to an issue that doesn't exists. Besides, if you want to keep your code cross-platform, you have to **properly configure** your build environment (and do use precompiled headers). The [/FI (Name Forced Include File)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx) compiler switch is what you'd use on Visual Studio when using precompiled header files, without including the precompiled header file (stdafx.h by default).